# "Farthest" vs. "furthest"

Tags: synonyms, confusables

My spellchecker insists on replacing "furthest" with "farthest". I was under the impression that *farthest* is strictly speaking in terms of distance, whereas *furthest* is more abstract.

[A poster on this forum](http://www.mywriterscircle.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=7be4d1d47ff23b42bce066b0e3091978&topic=18407.msg257987#msg257987) gives the following example:

> The further [quantity] you walk, the farther [distance] you get.

What gives?

Comment: Related: [When should “farther” and “further” be used?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/)

Comment: Well, we know that spell checkers aren't very bright.      http://www.latech.edu/tech/liberal-arts/geography/courses/spellchecker.htm

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The NOAD I had on my Mac Mini reported the following note, which is the same note found on the *Oxford Living Dictionaries* about [*farther*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/farther) and *farthest*.

> Traditionally, *farther* and *farthest* were used in referring to physical distance: *the falls were still two or three miles farther up the path*. *Further* and *furthest* were restricted to figurative or abstract senses: *we decided to consider the matter further*.   Although *farther* and *farthest* are still restricted to measurable distances, *further* and *furthest* are now common in both senses: *put those plants the furthest from the window*.

Comment: For some active examples: *I must investigate **further** before making any conclusions.* vs. *I have moved **farther** from the city because the environment is much nicer here.**

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with the answer above. I rarely hear "farther" or "farthest" anymore. Most people say "further" these days. I was just watching some Olympic coverage on the CBC (Canadian Broadcasting Corporation) and the commentators always used "further" when describing ski jumping distance. Most people seem to think "further" sounds better, and they'd rather not have to think about which word to choose, so they simply default to that.

Answer (score 1):

In a grammar book l bought recently I found an enty which read as follows ;Far-further, furthest.    When I went to school we were taught that the comparative adjective  Far became farther than ,when we talk about physical distance . Bari is Farther from Milan than Venice.
Further is used in an abstact sense.  He arrived further up in his career than his sister.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Pam. Thank you for your answer, but please provide the  name of the book where you found the information you mention. Try to write to the best of your ability, with correct punctuation and spelling. Read ["How do I write a good answer?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to find tips on how to write great answers.