# Comparative or superlative use of the word "far"

Tags: comparatives, superlative-degree

Which sentence is correct?

The quarterback threw the ball farthest than anyone else on the team.

The quarterback threw the ball farther than anyone else on the team.

The quarterback threw the ball further than anyone else on the team.

Comment: The first option is certainly incorrect. I believe in "correct" usage, "farther" refers to physical distance, "further" is used for metaphorical distance though I would argue the "further" has much more widespread use.

Comment: i.e. I threw the ball farther to further my skills.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of   [When should “farther” and “further” be used?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4407),  or of   [“Farthest” vs. “furthest”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/19680),

Comment: ‘The idea that “farther” and “further” work in different realms is not sustainable. The Oxford Dictionary (1989) comments that C19 usage on this point was often arbitrary; and Webster’s English Usage (1989) notes that both forms are now freely applied to “spatial, temporal or metaphorical distance.”. ('The Cambridge Guide to English Usage')

Answer (score 1):

How many quarterbacks are there? If there is one quarterback, he can throw **far**.

If there are two quarterbacks, one can throw **farther** than the other.

You need a comparison between **three** of a thing to use **farthest** (or biggest, tallest, smartest, etc.)

If everybody on the team is throwing the ball, then you'd be technically correct to say he threw the farthest (if he did).

The difference between farther and further is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

As JamesWebster points out, the use of *further* instead of *farther* is widespread, which is OK, I guess.

The old rule about *farther* being a *literal distance*, whether a hundred feet or a million miles, and *further* being a *figurative distance*, as in "the furthest thing from my mind," allows for a more accurate expression. However, people generally know intuitively when you say "furthest thing from my mind" you are not talking about a literal distance. Moreover, "a little further down the road" is clearly a literal expression (in most instances), and people generally will not be surprised if you attach a literal distance to the expression, as in "oh, about a mile-and-a-half down the road."

It's dealer's choice as to how you roll in the farther/further locution. In formal writing, I think you are better off observing the difference between the literal and the figurative. I have a feeling, moreover, people might look askance if you say, "That's the farthest thing from my mind," though I could be wrong.

Comment: Who came up with this *farther/further* distinction? And when? The 1892 *Webster's International Dictionary* doesn't seem to make it.

Comment: @PeterShor: Yeah, you're probably right. Personally, I'm comfortable with a distinction between the two terms, but I wouldn't correct someone who uses the terms interchangeably (or uses just one term all the time). "Poe-tah-toe, poe-tay- toe; toe-mah-toe, toe-may-toe!  Let's call the whole thing off" (the Gershwin brothers).

Comment: Googling old grammar books, it looks like this distinction was made in the mid-19th Century; the motivation seems to be that *farther* is the comparative of *far*, and *further* is the comparative of *fore/forth*. Indeed, *further* is etymologically the comparative of *fore/forth*, and it displaced *farrer* as the comaprative of *far* some time during Middle English. But I'm not convinced there was any distinction between the two before the grammarians introduced one.

Comment: @PeterShor: Thanks for the etymological insights! Don