# Direction-most or Farthest / Furthest for cardinal points on a map?

Tags: diction, direction

I am creating an app which will allow the user to designate the bounds of the map. I will let them set the points most north, south, east, and west (latitude and longitude).

I am wondering about the verbiage I should use. Right now I've got:

```
Northernmost
Southernmost
Farthest West
Farthest East
```

Is this right? Why not Westernmost and Easternmost? It just doesn't sound right to me, but I don't know why.

Should they all be "-most"?

Should they all be "farthest" or "furthest"?

Or should it be a mixture, such as:

```
Northernmost
Southernmost
Farthest West
Furthest East
```

?

Comment: For a map, though, you are actually setting *boundary lines* rather than points, as the resulting map will be a square and not diamond shaped.  So you set a North border line, a South line, an East Line and a West Line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Easternmost](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/easternmost)* and *[westernmost](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/westernmost)* are both valid English words.

Also, to answer the second part of your question, from a strict grammatical sense, you should use *farthest*, not *furthest*.  *Farthest* is used when describing distance, while *furthest* is used to describe abstract concepts.  However, in today's English, the distinction has been blurred.  For more information, see this ELU answer:  ["Farthest" vs. "furthest"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19680/farthest-vs-furthest)