# What is the difference between "farthermost" and "furthermost"?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *farthermost* and *furthermost*? In most cases, a quick Google search for the "word vs word" returns the answer on the first page. Not for this one.

Comment: I believe one is just a variant of the other

Comment: "Farthermost" sounds odd to me. I speak AmE. It's listed as a word in my AmE dictionary. I don't think I've ever used the word, even in contexts where I would use "farther." Am I the only AmE speaker who thinks it sounds funny? I think I just use "furthermost" in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As implied above, the distinction is the same as that between [“farther” versus “further”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/when-should-farther-and-further-be-used).

When the distance is literal – physical distance in space – use “farther”. When the distance is only figurative, use “further”.